# How to force azure pipeline to use a specific msbuild version

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, pipeline

Since there currently is an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/8718) in sdk 7.0.302 with MSBuild 17.6.x not building razor files in certain situations, our build pipeline now fails. It used to build fine with sdk 7.0.203 using msbuild version 17.5.1. The sdk version was set in the yaml like this:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
   displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK 7.0.x'
   inputs:
     packageType: 'sdk'
     version: '7.0.x'
```

I already changed it to use sdk 7.0.203, which corresponds to visual studio version 17.5.4. The sdk version now shows correct, but unfortunately it still builds with MSBuild version 17.6.1:

```
Starting: Build
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.221.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
C:\Agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe build C:\Agent\_work\7\s\Gigantisch.Afas.Api\Gigantisch.Afas.Api.csproj "-dl:CentralLogger,\"C:\Agent\_work\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.221.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"*ForwardingLogger,\"C:\Agent\_work\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.221.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"" --configuration Release
**MSBuild version 17.6.1+8ffc3fe3d for .NET**
```

Attempts to use any 17.5 version failed. I tried setting the sdk to version 7.0.202 in combination with added paramater "vsVerion: '17.5.2'" according to the [releases-list](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/7.0/releases.json) with it keeps building with 17.6.1. Switching to MSBuild@1 in stead of DotNetCoreCLI@2 to do the building  did not work either, since with MSBuild it is only possible to use major versions, like '17.0'.

Is it possible to force the use of 17.5.1 for MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

I run this -> **Dotnet --version**

version -> 7.0.203

Locally and then set the same SDK in my CI as

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Install .NET SDK
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '$(DotNetVersion)'  -> 7.0.203
        installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
        includePreviewVersions: false
```

This gives me the exact same `MSBuild` as I use to build Locally

Comment: Setting the version to '$(DotNetVersion)' resulted in an error::

'Version $(DotNetVersion) is not allowed. Allowed version types are: majorVersion.x, majorVersion.minorVersion.x, majorVersion.minorVersion.patchVersion.'

Setting it to 7.0.203 was allowed, as before. No change to the MSBuild version however. Still 17.6.1 is used, no matter your installationPath-value.